# How can it be true that this site works by popular vote when no one can vote until they get to a certain reputation?

Tags: discussion, questions

How can it be true that this site works by popular vote when no one can vote until they get to a certain reputation?

The statement is not accurate.  I saw a very inaccurate meaning of a gesture that people thought it meant, yet it doesn't mean it is accurate and it doesn't always mean the same to each person especially depending on when (time) and where you live!

Let's make things fair for everyone and not just for those who use this site, so getting a more accurate indication of opinion instead of only that from people who have the reputation 15 needed to vote!

Comment: It's like that so that people passing by can't vote casually. The popular vote applies to you too: if you've already provided respected information, then you can vote. That means you must have taken the trouble to ask a question or answer one and receive two upvotes, or an accepted answer. Welcome to Stack Exchange! May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help)? If you haven't even done that, why should you vote?

Comment: Allowing 1 rep users to vote has actually been discussed on Stack Exchange Meta, and very recently too. But it is not a popular proposal, and I doubt it will be go forward. [If more users could vote, would they engage more? **Testing 1 reputation voting on some sites**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on) It's also worth noting that everyone on this site started with 1 rep, we all had to do our bit in order to earn these "privileges"

Comment: Popular vote here is the vote of the 'populus' of this site, which amounts to the vote of those who have shown some (in fact, rather minimal) commitment to it. That's not different from what is meant by popular vote in other contexts: for example, no matter how democratic a country may be, it won't allow somebody who is just passing through it to vote in its elections.

Comment: We are very tolerant of new users who find the structure of Stack Exchange sites difficult to understand, being different from other question and answer sites. However we do ask that new users — especially those who are critical — read about the site to find out its rationale. You have not finished reading the [Tour] (we know because you don't have the badge) which explains the SE philosophy. Please do so, and perhaps the Help, which expands on different aspects. And I edited out your immoderate language. That really does not help your argument.

Answer (score 7):

If you think something isn't accurate, write an answer which is.

Currently to cast a downvote here you need to have a score of 125 reputation points on this site. You get those points by making a positive contribution. To start making a positive contribution, write an accurate answer.

There are other ways of gaining points, but as each upvote you get on an answer is worth 10, that's by far the easiest way.

Comment: Plus, every time you downvote an answer or a question, you lose points. This is not recommended for new users.

Comment: Well, since users can't be new users by the time they can downvote, that could be moot.